# Can a gentile make a tallit?

Tags: gentiles, tallit-gadol

I am in an interfaith marriage, and I have a small business making and selling kippot.  I have a client who has asked me to make a matching tallit for an upcoming special event.  My understanding is that a tallit is a more significant religious item.  I believe a tallis is different, because you say a blessing(ish?) when you tie the tzitzit. Also a kippah is a head covering and not inherently special.

I am certainly, technically able to make one, but I am uncertain as to whether my doing so would be problematic, as I am not Jewish.  According to halacha can a gentile make one with tzitzit?  If not, can a gentile make one *without* tzitzit and have a Jew attach them?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for bringing your question here.  I've edited to add the information you provided in comments.  You can [edit] further if you want to add anything (or if other people have questions).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Shulchan Aruch O"C 14:1 it says:

> ציצית שעשאן אינו יהודי פסול, דכתיב: "דבר אל בני ישראל", לאפוקי אינו יהודי
>
> Tzitzis that a non-Jew made are invalid, for it says, "Speak to the Children of Israel (Num. 15:38)" to exclude a non-Jew.

And the Mishnah Berurah there:

> **...שעשאן** — פי' שהטילן בבגד פסול אפילו בישראל עומד על גבו ומלמדהו לעשות לשמה
>
> **that made** - meaning: that tied them to the clothes - are invalid, even if a Jew stands over him and teaches him to do it for the sake [of the commandment]...

So it is permitted for a non-Jew to make the cloth, but attaching the strings would render it invalid.

Comment: True, but he can still do it afaik.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit to include the relevant information that I am technically able and would be making them for use by Jewish people of varying levels of observance.