# What are some religious items that a gentile can make and still be kosher, if any at all?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, mitzvah, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

I'm a gentile. I'm talking about items related to the fulfillment of mitzvot and there are some that are not so obvious to me, they are:

- tefillin(just the boxes and straps)
- tallitot
- shofarot
- sukkot
- mezuzah cases
- menorot
- burial shrouds

Also, it's okay for a gentile to print religious books?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya, Leonardo, this is a great first question!

Comment: This about a tallis: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79527/can-a-gentile-make-a-tallit

Comment: This about a Sukkah: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85995/can-the-entire-succah-be-constructed-by-a-gentile

Comment: And the opening paragraphs here provide a good background context - https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/19070#1b

Comment: @sabba The Soncino press made the first printed Talmud, who happened to be Jews, but you're right that Bomberg wasn't a Jew. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_incunabula#Table_of_incunabula

Comment: This is about tefillin. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93970/can-any-part-of-stam-making-be-done-by-a-gentile